# Как сформировать словарь с наименованием организации, ИНН и ОГРН

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью re получить из следующей строки словарь:

```
'ООО "П.Б. Ромашка"  (ИНН: 00000000, ОГРН: 9999999)'
```

Хотелось бы получить

```
{'Наименование': 'ООО "П.Б. Ромашка"', 'ИНН': '00000000', 'ОГРН':'9999999'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если конкретно из указанной, то, например, так:

```
s = 'ООО "П.Б. Ромашка"  (ИНН: 00000000, ОГРН: 9999999)'
r = re.match("(.*?)\s+\(.*:\s+(.*),.*:\s+(.*)\)", s)
d = {'Наименование': r.group(1), 'ИНН': r.group(2), 'ОГРН': r.group(3)}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что надо.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [88]: import re

In [89]: pat = r'([^\(]*)\s+\(([^:\,\s]*):[\s]*(\d+)[\,\s]+([^:]*)[:\s]+([^\)]*)\)*'

In [90]: m = re.search(pat, s, flags=re.U)

In [91]: print(m.groups())
('ООО "П.Б. Ромашка" ', 'ИНН', '00000000', 'ОГРН', '9999999')
```

дальнейшая задача тривиальная - создать словарь из элементов кортежа...

где:

```
In [92]: s
Out[92]: 'ООО "П.Б. Ромашка"  (ИНН: 00000000, ОГРН: 9999999)'
```